# Word VBA to change the header for one section

Tags: vba, ms-word

So in my document it copies some tables from Access, pastes them into Word with:

```
' Paste into word
wd.ActiveDocument.Sections(i).Range.Select
wd.Selection.Paste
```

It then formats the table, then it inserts a section break at the very end with:

```
' Insert a new section
wd.ActiveDocument.Characters.Last.Select
wd.Selection.Collapse
wd.Selection.Range.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
```

Then it starts the cycle over: it copies a table from Access and pastes it into the new section. I'm trying to update the header for just this new section, but it is updating all headers.

```
' Write to the header of this section
With wd.ActiveDocument.Sections(i).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
    .Text = Chr(10) & headerText
    .Font.Size = 18
    .Font.Name = "Tahoma"
    .Font.Bold = True
    .ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 6
    .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
End With
```

Suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: .linktoprevious should be false

Comment: Yep, that did it.

Comment: @Freeflow Do you want to provide an answer so I can accept it? I don't want to take credit for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The continuity of the text in Headers and Footers is controlled by the .LinkToPrevious property.  This property can be set independently for each of the three types of Header and Footer.  If the property is set to 'True' then the current Header/Footer inherits the text from the previous same type of Header/Footer.  If it is set to 'False' then you can put different text in the header/Footer.